# Repairing a specific file or folder in windows 7 with chkdsk or alternative program

Tags: windows-7, command-line, ntfs, chkdsk

I have a 500 GB NTFS partition on which there is a folder that I know contains some bad sectors.So to save time and resources, Is there any possible way to run chkdsk or alternative program to repair that specific file or folder?

Comment: what I need is a tool to check a specific folder or file for bad sectors then remaps them.All my data are videos and I don't care about recovering the exisiting data.I got the videos from a private tracker so recovering  is easy.

Comment: All the repair tools, I know of, do the whole drive, and a few offer the ability to set a starting and some and ending sector.  However, files/folders are split across dozen if not hundreds/thousands of sectors and individual files can be fragmented and scattered all over the drive.  Therefore setting the start/end location can not be used to target a given file/folder.

Comment: First check SMART to determine if you want to remap even. If drive is like Swiss cheese you better clone  + replace it. Although you may know about a few both sectors you do not know if they're the only bad sectors. You can run something Like HD Sentinel or Victoria for Windows to run surface scan and 'force' remaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run chkdisk with the /F and /R triggers to fix and recover. However, you may have to move on to more proper data recovery tools. For this I have had great results with both Testdisk and Ontrack's data recovery tools. If you end up recovering the raw data, it may not be pretty (lost filenames, corrupt/unreadable files) but you will recover whatever usable data there is on the drive.